# Regular Expression to add a Scope for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: regex, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

does anyone know a regular expression or another way how it is possible to replace the Bootstrap css class names with a individual scope? I want to include bootstrap into WordPres admin area, but there are some class conflicts.

```
.btn{ ....
```

Should become:

```
.myscope .btn{ ....
```

Any ideas?
-thx-

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 2nd stylesheet -- say, `admin-bootstrap.css` -- and then load it only on the admin screens using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'pjso_admin_bootstrap_styles' );
function pjso_admin_bootstrap_styles() {
    // remove the existing Bootstrap styles
    wp_dequeue_style( 'bootstrap' ); 
    // assuming that the Bootstrap styles have the handle 'bootstrap'
    $handle = 'bootstrap-admin';
    $src = '/path/to/your/stylesheet.css';
    $deps = array(

    );  // stylesheet dependencies go in the array
    // load up the Bootstrap Admin styles
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps );
}
```

#### References

- [`admin_enqueue_scripts` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)
- [`wp_dequeue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style)
- [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: Hi, thx for your help, but that doesn`t fix the problem. I know how to enqueue the script, but the problem is, that bootstrap contains serveral global classes (body, input, table...), which changes the WordPress admin styles and layout. In jQuery UI for example you can add a individual scope at the download page to fix these problems.